# What are the full details of the Kurta Clan's destruction and what was Kurapika's role during it? Was he present?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Kurapika was the only member of the Kurta Clan to survive. How? What happened to him? Did he watch his clan die? I know his past life and motive for getting revenge on the Phantom Troupe is mostly just for the story plot, but I still don't understand the full thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The circumstances of the slaughter of the Kurta clan are described in the special two-chapter volume *Kurapika's Memories* by Yoshihiro Togashi ( https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Volume_0 ), specifically at the end of part 2.

The clan was slaughtered some time in the 6 weeks following Kurapika's departure (so no, he wasn't there). Details about signs of torture and eyeballs having been removed from the bodies, along with a message left by unnamed culprits, were reported in the news. Unbeknownst to all the members but Kurapika and his late friend Pairo, Kurapika's actions before leaving had prompted information about their otherwise secretive clan to be leaked to a nearby community, presumably allowing what we know is the Phantom Troupe to find them.

Comment: thank you, that helped.